# Sagepay Issue - Retrieve a Transaction not working after 3D-Secure Authenticate

Tags: payment, opayo, 3d-secure

https://developer.sage.com/api/payments/api/#operation/retrieveTransaction

After **3D-Secure Authenticate**, I can't retrieve transaction using **transactionId**. I'm getting the following response :

```
{
    "description": "Transaction not found",
    "code": 1012
}
```

Sometimes it's working fine. then it's a response like this:

```
{
    "statusCode": "0000",
    "statusDetail": "The Authorisation was Successful.",
    "transactionId": "5D208A72-C1A6-68E7-A61D-B67D51CXXXXX",
    "transactionType": "Payment",
    "retrievalReference": 6764XXX,
    "bankResponseCode": "00",
    "bankAuthorisationCode": "999XXX",
    "paymentMethod": {
        "card": {
            "cardType": "Visa",
            "lastFourDigits": "0006",
            "expiryDate": "0720",
            "cardIdentifier": "8B27BE84-E06C-4F88-ADCD-AFF22EBXXXXX",
            "reusable": false
        }
    },
    "amount": {
        "totalAmount": 13500,
        "saleAmount": 13500,
        "surchargeAmount": 0
    },
    "currency": "GBP",
    "fiRecipient": {},
    "status": "Ok",
    "avsCvcCheck": {
        "status": "AllMatched",
        "address": "Matched",
        "postalCode": "Matched",
        "securityCode": "Matched"
    },
    "3DSecure": {
        "status": "Authenticated"
    }
}
```

Does anybody know How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue. I am using the test sandbox environment and forcing 3dsv1.0 processing. In 3DS version 1 , after the challenge/response returns it does not give the full transaction details, so you then need to query sagepay to get the authorisation status. As stated above it either returns the transaction object successfully OR quite randomly gives  `{"description":"Transaction not found","code":1012}`.
I then assumed some timing issue - so put in place a retry option below to query the transaction. This appeared to assist things (meaning "sometimes" it got the transaction) but was not a fix in itself.

```
async.retry({ 
    times: 10, 
    interval: function(retryCount) {
        return 50 * Math.pow(2, retryCount);
    },
    errorFilter: function(errorCode) {
         return errorCode === 404; // only retry on transaction 'not-found'
    },
 },
 function (callback) { 
     return getSageTransactionStatus(MD, callback) 
 },
 function(err, result) {
     if (err) {
         if (global.gLogging ) console.log ("Transaction Search Result", err);
     }
     else console.log (result);
 });
```

Comment: Update: SagePay tech support confirm today that the "issue is a known problem on test accounts including the sandbox accounts". They are working on a fix. ETA not known as of yet. They say it is not a problem on the live accounts.

Comment: Hi PaulC, how did you get on with Opayo/SagePay, I've just seen the 1012 in live environment which taking the same request later did return successfully. Their support is typically useless so not holding out much hope. I think since the original developers left its pretty much abandonware on API development, btw, did you figure out how to submit client IP on 3dV1?

Comment: Hi Matt, the issue at that time was only on their test environments and were "fixed" within a day or so with little explanation. Their helpdesk are geared towards payment support and are certainly unable to support the API. That said i have seen this issue on production like you. it happened in Jan this year after 3Dv2 was introduced. overall the issue was that Opayo were having issues dealing with transaction status across the overall platform so not specifically an api issue.  This is more an issue re 3dv1 rather that 3dv2 as in v2 the transaction status gets returned automatically unlike v1

Comment: Hi Matt, also to add concerning IP. You have to fill out the strongCustomerAuthentication block of the api call with the IP address. ( i also use the npm module @supercharge/request-ip to extract the IP as it handles "finding" the IP address within the browser post request).  My recollection is that concerning 3dv1 this block is not needed as such but is for v2. That said i provide it to any 3d calls whether v1 or v2. regards,paul

Comment: Hi PaulC, we dont have things like user-agent/accept/browsersize in the middleware yet for v2, thus on 3dv1 and we dont submit a strongCustomerAutnetication block in our req payload so far, so are you saying we can just use the SCA bock for the IP (and ignore the other required fields) and we'll still be okay on 3dv1 you think? Heard back from SagePay on 1012, it is in production too "
You need to wait at least 1 second before attempting a request against a transaction to allow the Sage Pay systems to update." so we've added a sleep basically

Comment: Hi Matt, re 1012...yes that was what i did too. So the code above queried opayo and then retried it in a stepped-back manner (allowing more time to elapse) until the reply came through. Re IP - yes i submit the SCA block for v1 and v2 where we give all the mandatory fields. The opayo documentation outlines the mandatory fields and the dependent ones etc.  But i am curious why you are submitting the IP address for 3D v1 in the first place? I only added any such SCA references when doing V2. Then i saw that you could submit the SCA block regardless of V1 or V2 (and i assume V1 ignores it anyway)

Comment: The client IP shows in the sagepay admin ux, which is hand for inspecting transactions when doing fraud forensics, but more importantly a client relies on the totally pathetic Thirdman analysis (it's comically bad - and well replace it eventually with a 50 lines of basic IF statements) and that always shows up "IP doesnt match billing address country -10 points".. as the IP it has is that of the server submitting...

Comment: I'm a little confused though, I thought it fell back to V1 when didnt have enough info for V2 due not completing SCA block properly (or omitting it completely), are you able to force V1 even with a complete SCA block that should be compatible with V2?  I look forward to the day we can leave this poorly documented abandonware API - I have some gripes with Adyen but in comparison it's night and day better.

Comment: On the Opayo test environments you can force 3dv1 or 3dv2 in your payment submission. On production, you are correct. It is the user's card-issuing bank who calls the shots. When you submit a payment you end up either having to process a v1 or v2 response. The SCA block as you point out cant force it either way. I provide the SCA block regardless but of  course anything in this block cant force 3dv1 -- it just allows me to send "the 3d stuff" over the fence . if 3dv1 kicks in well the SCA block is likely ignored . Re IP ..agree as we use azure and therefore the IPswont always match either!

Comment: Adyen looks like a far more proactive solution , just from browsing their offering ( i have not used them myself). Also stripe. Opayo need to seriously address the API support side of things.